# iphone app time counter

Tags: iphone

I would like to create a time counter in my app that shows the user how many minutes the app has been running the current session and total. How do I create such time counter and how do I save the value to the phone? I'm new to app developement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` classes for this.

Here's an example:

Declare an NSDate instance in your .m file:

```
@implementation MyClass 

NSDate *startDate;
BOOL stopTimer = NO;
//...    

-(void) showElapsedTime: (NSTimer *) timer {
    if(!startDate) {
        startDate = [NSDate date]; 
    }
    NSTimeInterval timeSinceStart = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *newDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:timeSinceStart sinceDate:startDate];
    NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:newDate dateStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];


    //do something with dateString....

    if(stopTimer) {//base case
       [timer invalidate];
    }
    [newDate release];
}

- (void) startPolling {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.09f target:self selector:@selector(showElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

//...

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. how can I save this in iPhone's database? (save newDate on app exit)

Comment: one last thing- how do I add two dates? newDate + totalDate

Comment: Try `NSDate *addedDate = [newDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:[newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]];`

Comment: Do I need to use a loop to keep refreshing the time counter?

Comment: Sure. Trying to get NSUserDefaults to save data. It's not working. I put it viewDidUnload. Also, where should I load the data on app start.

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: @Sam, catch me on AIM. My name lowercase without spaces.

Comment: im online now. ran in to another problem. NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date]; //initializer element not a constant

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone you can use the API [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html) to get a numeric value for the current date and time. You can call this twice and subtract the two numbers from each other to get an elapsed time between those calls. You can then save that elapsed time between executions of your program to save the total time the user has had your program running.

Comment: The simplest way to store data is perhaps by using NSUserDefaults. You can then progress to using Core Data (for better flexibility) as your knowledge of the API increases.